# Reference Folders vs. Nested Projects

Tags: git, svn, version-control, xcode7, reference-folders

I am currently working on a nested project setup in Xcode which at the time made things quite organised except for the framework + bundle targets for each project added to the application project. Never the less, I am confident to say that it organised our code extensibly. As the project has continued to grow, this organisation has become more of a time consumption during the build process, not to mention that the inner settings for each project are something that one always has to keep at the top of the list when adding a new nested project.

For some time now I've been trying to find alternatives to this setup, and folder references has been the one that has my complete attention. Switching to this setup should speed up any build process to follow. I just don't know how easy it will be to have those references with unique repository locations in order to have multiple people access each and every part of the overall project. We also currently use SVN for version control, but are very open to other alternatives as I have been trying excessively for the project to be moved to Git.

This leads me to my question, how to setup the folders in their own repository and also the application project? Which version control is more suitable for this type of setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with simple SVN folders but adding them as groups to the project. This allowed me to create all types of files Xcode supports without struggles as well as being able to make use of version control and collaboration with the team.

Reference folders was limiting the way to add files to it. Not that you wouldn't be able to add objective-c interface and implementation files but you would have to do it one by one and then specifying the extension for each. That and the having to use full path for files was just not very attractive at all, at least not for the setup we were looking for which is a package/feature setup.

Nested projects was doing the job just fine, keeping files organised by feature or functionality. We had definitions in a framework product and simply added a bundle for the resources, things like xibs, images unique to the portion, any text files, etc. The issues we found with this was the continuous linking of the projects' framework and bundle to the main application. The biggest issue I personally saw was the large time consumption building the application, or even worse to archive it, as every nested project needed to build as a pre-requisite to the application build to complete.

With this new setup, the build speeds have been reduced dramatically. You don't have to handle different project settings. We still have a framework for some packaged files we offer, but it is more like a combination of both when it comes down to the application and it's features.